# uncaught error no module when I inject $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have no idea what have gone wrong, I saw **uncaught error no module : myModule** in the console after I start to use `$http`.

After research, I found even angular official page have the same problem, [at this URL](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$animate:notcsel)

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: go to the url above, and inspect element

Comment: I don't see that error, what browser are you using?

Comment: I also don't see the No module error. Do you have some type of ad block software that blocks the CDN loading of the javascript libraries? If you inspect element & look at the network tab, do you see any red entries?

Comment: I open with private browsing in Chrome then the error is no longer appear. Maybe some extension caused the problem.